# Coq: Defining a function by pattern matching on the arity of its argument

Tags: function, match, definition, coq

I want to define a function, the behavior of which depends on whether it's argument is (at least) an n-place function. A rudimentary (failed) attempt is

```
Definition rT {y:Type}(x:y) := ltac: (match y with
 | _ -> _ -> _ => exact True
 | _ => exact False end).

Check prod: Type -> Type -> Type.
Compute rT prod. (*= False: Prop*)
Print rT. (*rT = fun (y : Type) (_ : y) => False: forall y : Type, y -> Prop*)
```

As you see, `rT` maps everything to `False`. Why? The result remains the same if I replace `y` in the match clause w/ `type of x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want cannot exist within Gallina at the type you expect.

Your function is accepted, but if you print it, you can see its body is:

```
rT = fun (y : Type) (_ : y) => False
```

Gallina has no way of `match`-ing on a `Type`. There are ways to deal with n-ary functions, in such a way that you can inspect their arity, but it involves dependent types to statically capture the arity. For instance, for uniform n-ary functions:

https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.NaryFunctions.html

Comment: Is the reason behind this that Coq's pattern matching is designed to work only on constructors of an inductive type?

Comment: There are two levels of pattern matching. The "Gallina" pattern matching indeed only works on inductive and coinductive types. The "Ltac" pattern matching that your code is using is more syntactic, so what it does cannot be expressed as a Gallina term (in general).